# sending events from elasticsearch to centroen

Tags: elasticsearch

community,

I am seeking assistance with sending events from Elasticsearch to Centreon. I have been working on this for a week now, but I'm unable to find the right documentation or guidance from Elasticsearch and Centreon. If any of you have experience with this integration or have ideas about how to achieve it, I would greatly appreciate your help. Please share your knowledge or point me in the right direction.

Thank you, and have a nice day.

i had tried with elasticsearch and centreon documentation